# Same rest service invoked concurrently

Tags: php, web-services, rest, concurrency

I created a simple web service REST in PHP as follows

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")&&($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]=="/myService")){  
  $payload=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);                  
    $class= new ClassA();
    $class->runFunction($payload["myParameter"]);

} else {
  header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
  echo("Error");  
}
```

and this is the function in ClassA

```
function runFunction($myParameter)
{

if (empty($myParameter)){                  
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
   echo("Error"); 
}
else
{
    ob_start();
    echo("Ok service invoked");  
    $size=ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: {$size}");
    ob_end_flush(); *//I use this to continue processing php after response*
    ob_flush();
    flush();

  **HERE THERE IS A switch($myParameter)
  WITH DIFFERENT FUNCTION** 

    }   
}
```

So my question is what happens if during the execution of some operation after point X the web service is invoked again?
Can the script handle the new request without stopping the first?

I have this doubt because I checked the log file after a test and it seems the script stopped processing of first request when /myService was invoked the second time with a new parameter.

If is there this problem, how can I modify my script?

Thank you very much

Comment: Each call to the service will start a totally seperate instance of this script

Comment: @RiggsFolly so what happened during my test? A momentary network problem? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Maybe its because of what is happening in `**HERE THERE IS A switch($myParameter)  WITH DIFFERENT FUNCTION**` But how would we know

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't know because during my "single invocation test" everything works well.  the flow of the script is :
1) service invoked with parameter=1 -> switch direct to a function in witch I use CURL with GET to retrieve some data and then with PUT. If all it's ok I invoke an API (external system) to set a parameter  
2)service invoked with parameter=2 -> other operation

During my test, the script stopped first "execution" (with param=1) after PUT (without invoking external API even if it was all ok) and started running the second "execution" (always with param=1)